# Gap created when collapsing Bootstrap's collapsible panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have a problem with a Bootstrap's collapsible panel
When a collapsible panel is collapsed after being shown a blank gap of the same size appears in its place.

This is happening while using Firefox (not in Chrome) and the gap dissapears if the page is resized (zoom in, zoom out).

Fragments of code involving the problematic panel:

```
<div class="panel panel-default cl-orange">
    <a class="" href="#newAircraftType" data-toggle="collapse">
        <div class="panel-agregar">
            <div class="panel-plus">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<!--Collapsible panel-->
<div id="newAircraftType" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="">
    <div class="panel-body crear-operador form-horizontal panel-box detalle-panel-body">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some screenshots:

[Panel shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THYeb.png)

[Panel collapsed and gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsG9T.png)

[Panel collapsed without gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qff0j.png)

Comment: Can you provide a link or a fiddle?

Comment: I think there must be any closing tag is missing, because can't see any issue with your above given code.

Comment: It's not possible to provide a link or a fiddle. If there is a missing closing tag, why is it been rendered correctly when zoom in/out or in chrome without any problems?